# Executing batch file times out on certain commands

Tags: c#, batch-file, process

I'm executing a batch file with the following code:

```
using (var process = new Process())
{
   process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
   process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c \"\"" + batchFile + "\"\"";
   process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
   process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

   var output = new StringBuilder();
   var error = new StringBuilder();

   using (var outputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
   using (var errorWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
   {
      process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
      {
         if (e.Data == null)
         {
            outputWaitHandle.Set();
         }
         else
         {
            output.AppendLine(e.Data);
         }
       };

       process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
       {
          if (e.Data == null)
          {
             errorWaitHandle.Set();
          }
          else
          {
             error.AppendLine(e.Data);
          }
       };

       process.Start();

       process.BeginOutputReadLine();
       process.BeginErrorReadLine();

       if (process.WaitForExit(30000) &&
           outputWaitHandle.WaitOne(30000) &&
           errorWaitHandle.WaitOne(30000))
           {
              Log("Batch file exit code: " + process.ExitCode + ".\nOutput: " + output + ".\nError ouput: " + error);
           }
           else
           {
              Log("The batch file timed out.");
           }
     }
   }
```

This code executes a batch file, and waits for it to complete. And it works fine when my batch file only outputs to a text file. But if my batch file contains the line `start "C:\Windows\System32" notepad.exe`, it times out. Why?

***EDIT***

I just realized that it hangs even if all I have in my batch file is `notepad.exe`, but it works fine if I'm writing to a text file. The exit code is `InvalidOperation`

***EDIT***

Even with this simple code, it won't open notepad. It doesn't throw any exception or anything either...

```
string notepadPath = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "notepad.exe");
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(notepadPath))
       Process.Start(notepadPath);
```

Comment: what do you mean times out.. does it launch notepad.exe..? or is that when it hangs.. have you tried using the literal symbol in the file path perhaps it's looking at `"\"` as an escape symbol.. have you stepped thru the code using the debugger to see even if particular things happen.. or don't happen as you have expected

Comment: It doesn't launch notepad.exe, it just hangs.

Comment: what if you changed this line `process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c \"\"" + batchFile + "\"\"";` to the following 
`process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c \"\\"" + batchFile + "\"\"";` why do you need the extra `"\"` at the end as well

Comment: For debugging purposes, I'd suggest setting `CreateNoWindow`, `RedirectStandardInput` and `RedirectStandardOutput` to `false`. That might give you some visibility into the problem (i.e. you might have some output in the console window).

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Task Manager` stats tab - I'm sure there are a lot of notepads there.
You are creating the `Process` with `StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;`. This prevents the `notepad` window to open, as no window - no notepad. Also the same behaviour is for `UseShellExecute = false;`.

Remove these lines and try out another time (and make sure if there is a `notepadPath` file exists, and the batch, if you run it manually, opens the notepad).

[According the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx):

```
// This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself.  
// Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it  
// on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it programmatically 
// from this application using the Kill method.
```

So you simply creating your process and batch is waiting for it to close, which won't never happen.

Comment: There are a lot of notepads in my `Task Manager` (and cmd too)! But removing those lines still won't display notepad...

Comment: And what do you expecting from the `notepad` with `process.BeginOutputReadLine();`? I think that you'll never got something from notepad

Comment: Okay, I just tried this code in a separate Console Application project and it worked fine. I think the problem is, that the application I'm running right now doesn't have a window itself, it's a process running in the background...so maybe it can't open any other window itself?

Comment: Hmmm, yes, I think that the problem is in here, as you can't open window in this manner.